# How we send email to customer for each product in One order in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4

we need to send mail to customer for each & every product in One order without spliting the order id in magento 2.4

Comment: You need to sent email after place order?

Comment: yes after place the order

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code and try.

1. Create a class to handle sending the email:

Here is the code:-

```
<?php
namespace YourVendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;

class Email extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_transportBuilder;
    protected $_inlineTranslation;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function sendProductEmail($order)
    {
        // Get the order items
        $orderItems = $order->getItems();

        // Loop through the order items
        foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
            // Get the product name
            $productName = $item->getName();
            // Get the product email template
            $templateId = 'product_email_template_id';
            // Get the sender information
            $sender = [
                'name' => 'Sender Name',
                'email' => 'sender@email.com',
            ];
            // Get the recipient information
            $recipient = [
                'email' => $order->getCustomerEmail(),
                'name' => $order->getCustomerName(),
            ];
            // Set the template variables
            $templateVars = [
                'product_name' => $productName,
            ];
            // Enable HTML emails
            $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();
            // Send the email
            $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()])
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo($recipient['email'], $recipient['name'])
                ->getTransport()
                ->sendMessage();
            // Re-enable HTML emails
            $this->_inlineTranslation->resume();
        }
    }
}
```

> **`sendProductEmail`** function call as your requirement plugin or observer where you want to send email.

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**